# Customize JTextField in Java Swings - add simple/compound/custom borders to JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a Netbeans java project with a lot of forms. There are many `JTextField`s in those forms. I would like to customize those text fields with a custom border.

```
 private void tfUserNameFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       
        tfUserName.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255)), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255))), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 4, 2, 0, new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))));
 }

private void tfUserNameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
        tfUserName.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204)), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 4, 2, 0, new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))));
}
```

I can add these code lines to each `JTextField`, but I'm looking for an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the same border for all `JTextField`s, use the [UIManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) class.

```java
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TextField.border", BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("George"));
```

The above code will set the default border for every `JTextField` to a titled border where the title is *George*.

`UIManager` class manages what is known as *look-and-feel*. I suggest reading the *javadoc* for class `UIManager`.

### EDIT

For changing the border when a `JTextField` gains or loses focus, use the `FocusEvent` parameter of the method `focusGained()` and method `focusLost()`. The parameter contains the "source" of the event.

```
evt.getSource()
```

You know that the source is a `JTextField` so just cast it and set the border.

```
JTextField textField = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
textField.setBorder( /* whatever border you need */ );
```

Comment: this will works i think, could you please give me some guidelines or sample codes about how change border with **event** using UIManager. IE: FocusGained or FocusLost.

Comment: @samgi `UIManager` is for setting _look-and-feel_ defaults and not for dynamically changing the border of a `JTextField`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own extension of JTextField like this:

```
public class OwnJTextField extends JTextField {
private void tfUserNameFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    tfUserName.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255)), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255))), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 4, 2, 0, new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))));
}
private void tfUserNameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    tfUserName.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204)), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 4, 2, 0, new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))));
}
```

And everywhere where you need that use OwnJTextField instead JTextField.